# Ask vim how many splits are in current tab

Tags: vim

I am trying to make a make a binding, `<Leader>t`, to toggle a specific split in and out of its own tab. The two commands are

```
" Open current split in a new tab
map <Leader>T <C-w>T
" Close current buffer (and thus the new tab)
map <Leader>t <C-w>c
```

How do I combine them? Something like

```
map <Leader>t numberOfSplitsInCurrentTab > 1 ? <C-w>T : <C-w>c
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question for others to learn from.

```
function! ToggleSingleSplit()
    if len(tabpagebuflist()) > 1
        :tabedit %
    else
        :close
    endif
endfunction

map <Leader>t :call ToggleSingleSplit()<CR>
```

There is probably a more concise way to do this, but reads well and is easy to edit for people like myself who is less versed in vimscript.

And for the curious, here are the resources I used:

- [Defining functions with if/else](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.7).
- [tabpagebuflist](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#tabpagebuflist()), found on this [function list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#function-list).
- [StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46827/vim-executing-a-key-command-in-a-function) on how to just execute commands.

Comment: I think that's a good way to do it. Also you if you have another question about vim you might be interested in posting it on [vi.stackexchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) which is dedicated to vi and vim topics ;)

Comment: Haha thanks... there will be. There will be, for sure.